# creating confirm dialog in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

```
$("#first").dialog({ width: 304, modal: true,

  beforeclose: function (e, ui) 
  {
        $("#confirm").dialog({ width: 500, modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    document.location.href = "/Home/Index";
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The dialog `#first` closes without waiting for the `#confirm` dialog to open. I know about `confirm()` function of javascript but i want to use dialog in this case . How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question and this is working fine:

```
$("#first").dialog({ width: 304, modal: true,

  beforeclose: function (e, ui) 
  {
        $("#confirm").dialog({ width: 500, modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Confirm": function () {
                    document.location.href = "/Home/Index";
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });
      return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: yaa its true @muistooshort +1

Comment: Explanation: First dialog is created and displayed. When you try to close it, the beforeClose event is triggered. In your handler for the beforeClose event, you display a secondary "confirm" dialog then return the value false, which prevents the first dialog from closing. When you click the button labeled "confirm" you are manually navigating away to /home/index. When you click cancel, you are closing the confirm modal manually.

Answer (score 8):

From the [fine manual](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-beforeClose):

> **beforeClose(event, ui)**
>
> Triggered when a dialog is about to close. If canceled, the dialog will not close.

So you want your `beforeClose` handler to `return false` to keep the dialog from closing:

```
beforeClose: function(e, ui) {
    $("#confirm").dialog({ width: 500, modal: true, /* ... */ });
    return false;
}
```

Your *Confirm* button changes the location so you don't have to worry about your `beforeClose` handler preventing the second dialog from closing the first one. If you weren't changing the page location then you'd need a flag of some sort to keep `beforeClose` from preventing all closes; something like this for example:

```
beforeclose: function(e, ui) {
     var $dlg = $(this);
     if($dlg.data('can-close')) {
         $dlg.removeData('can-close');
         return true;
     }
     $("#confirm").dialog({
         //...
         buttons: {
             Confirm: function() {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
                 $dlg.data('can-close', true);
                 $dlg.dialog('close');
             },
             Cancel: function() {
                 $(this).dialog('close');
             }
         }
     });
     return false;
 }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jYZpD/